# Why does ie9 start slowly?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I have a new laptop with Windows 7 operating system and Internet explorer 9. The IE9 starts slowly and I don't know the reason. I disabled the add ins and the problem still the same!

Any ideas?

**Update:** I removed google as homepage and I used blank instead and it now start quickly but I think this is still a problem!

Comment: What home page is loading?  Is there more than one loading?

Comment: have you installed the latest graphics drivers (new laptop does not mean drivers are up to date or installed at all)?

Comment: Google. No it is just one loading (google).

Comment: Is anything else loading slowly, or is there plenty of RAM? I don't know why, but lately on my Win7 box when I open IE sometimes it spawns like 5 instances, but only one shows up. This could be what's happening to you, but it's a long shot. Next time it happens, hit Cntrl-Alt-Del and see how many iexplorers are running.

Comment: I removed google as homepage and I used blank instead and it start quickly now but I think this is still a problem because I don't like to start with blank page!

Comment: What happens if you close it, then within a short time (before 10 minutes is up) you re-open it?  what happens if you use a different google?  http://www.google.com/xhtml  or http://www.google.im/

Answer (score 0):

A slow DNS lookup could result in a slow load.  Try another home page, blank home page or load a page by IP address.  After the slow load, does IE function normally?

As changing the homepage changes load time, check DNS and possible connection issue.  Try PINGing Google and see if you have a high latency or packet loss. Trace Route (Tracert for windows ) and see if the packets are experincing issues.

Try other home pages.

Try using the IP for Google. From here in NA, Google reports as 173.194.73.104.  If it loads fine using an IP, then there is a DNS issue.  That could be your ISP or a local router.  There could be a number of variables

Comment: Yes it does function normally.

Comment: I tried all that and still the same. Just starts quickly when I make the homepage blank!

Comment: What was the result for PING and TRACERT?  That will help resolve this.  Use the Google IP and report results

Comment: Actually I don't know how to do tracert!  and I tried other broswers (opera) and firefox and they all start quickly. only IE had this probelm